# component receiving new props but reference inside it not updating when using mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

So Im trying to access a prop that normally it should have been updated it 
I can see the store using my redux devTools and i can confirm that it has been updated.
but when i'm inside a function in my component the props seems to maintain its initial value for some reason

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ repos, page }) => ({  
  repos,
  page // page is 1 then gets updated in the store to 2 
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    getData: (page, dateString) => dispatch(getData(page, dateString))
  };
};

const ConnectedRepositoryList = ({
  alertOnBottom,
  page, // after updated in the store the component re-renders and page is 2
  getData,
  repos
}) => {
  const loadRepos = () => {
    const date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - 30);
    const dateString = date.toISOString().split("T")[0];
    getData(page, dateString); // here page is still 1  :(

  };
  useEffect(() => {
    loadRepos();
  }, []);

  const handleOnDocumentBottom = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("I am at bottom! ");
    loadRepos();
    if (alertOnBottom) {
      alert('Bottom hit! Too slow? Reduce "debounce" value in props');
    }
  }, [alertOnBottom]);

  return (
    my html
   );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `handleOnDocumentBottom` callback depends on `loadRepos` but you haven't included `loadRepos` in the dependency array so `handleOnDocumentBottom` is being memoized and retains its original value unless `alertOnBottom` changes. Since you are redeclaring `loadRepos` on every render, the `handleOnDocument` callback will refer to the `loadRepos` which was defined on the first render when `page` was `1`. You could add `loadRepos` to the dependency array for `handleOnDocumentBottom` but that kind of defeats the purpose of `useCallback` since `loadRepos` is a new reference on every render and `handleOnDocumentBottom` will get created on every render anyways.

Here are two options to retain the memoization but correct the behavior:

Option 1 - add `page` to the dependency array. The correct `loadRepos` reference will then be closed over in `handleOnDocumentBottom` whenever `page` changes but it's a bit tricky to follow the logic and realize that `page` is an implicit dependency of `loadRepos`. Also if `loadRepos` ends up depending on another value in the future you will need to update the `handleOnDocumentBottom` dependency array to avoid subtle bugs:

```
  const handleOnDocumentBottom = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("I am at bottom! ");
    loadRepos();
    if (alertOnBottom) {
      alert('Bottom hit! Too slow? Reduce "debounce" value in props');
    }
  }, [alertOnBottom, page]); // refresh `handleOnDocumentBottom` whenever page changes
```

Option 2 would be to make `loadRepos` a callback as well and then add it to the dependency array for `handleOnDocumentBottom`:

```
  const loadRepos = useCallback(() => {
    const date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - 30);
    const dateString = date.toISOString().split("T")[0];
    getData(page, dateString); // here page is still 1  :(

  }, [page]); // add page as a dependency here
  useEffect(() => {
    loadRepos();
  }, []);

  const handleOnDocumentBottom = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("I am at bottom! ");
    loadRepos();
    if (alertOnBottom) {
      alert('Bottom hit! Too slow? Reduce "debounce" value in props');
    }
  }, [alertOnBottom, loadRepos]); // add the memoized loadRepos here
```

Now if `loadRepos` gets any new dependencies or changes then `handleOnDocumentBottom` doesn't need to change and the dependency relationships are explicit.